# Turning Caps-Lock into Control is not permanent on MacBook Pro Retina

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, caps-lock

I want to act my caps-lock key as control-key. 
I'm going to preferences ⇒ keyboard ⇒ modifier keys... and say that caps lock should be acting as control.

This is working fine until I put the MacBookPro to sleep for longer time. When I open the lid again, the caps-lock is again working as caps lock.

Not believing that Apple is fixing this quick I'm posting this here in hope that someone knows how to work around this problem.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to get [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en), which is mainly used for remapping the Caps Lock key.

Check the first box, Change Caps Lock, and change the "keycode" on the right to 59 (the code for left control).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I tried Seil. But Seil requires setting caps-lock to "no action", which is also reset after longer sleeps..